# Change a photo on page with ccs ( :hover )

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm sure this is really freaking simple, but I must be overlooking some aspect. I have a static image that is displayed on a webpage when it is loaded. I have an unordered list with a few list items. I would like to change the displayed webpage image when the mouse hovers over one/each list item. I tried using the onmouseover HTML event, but could not figure that out and I would like to use CSS anyways so I tried using the :hover CSS selector but I can't seem to figure it out

```
<div class="responsive_right_side_block"><img class="responsive_image" height="214" src="images/axis.gif" width="145"></div>

<p class="p_not_1st">The three commonly referred to axis of rotation are:
   <ul class="ul_first">
      <li id="frontal">Frontal axis</li>
      <li>Sagittal axis</li>
      <li>Vertical axis</li>
   </ul>
</p>
```

Here is the CSS block that I currently have

```
<style>
#frontal:hover .responsive_image { 
    display: "images/sagittal.gif"; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: This may not work, since to hover to work the element either should be Siblings or Child for the `div` in your case it is completely outside.

Answer (score 0):

since ".responsive image" is not apart of your unordered list, you don't need to mention it in CSS. and instead of using the display value, use background. For your CSS code I would just type.

```css
<style>
#frontal:hover { 
    background: url("images/sagittal.gif") no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This will display the image on top of the list not on the image position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do what you want as follow :

```
  <script>
    window.onload = WinLoad;
    function WinLoad() {
    document.getElementById("frontal").addEventListener("mouseover", changeImage);
  
    function changeImage() {
      document.getElementById("responsive_image").src = "images/sagittal.gif";
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well .. your style says that

> "on the hover of the `li` item ... select the image inside this item".

That's because `#frontal:hover .responsive_image` is `Descendant combinator`. I suggest you to have a look on those topics [CSS selectors from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) & [CSS Selector Reference from W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

In your HTML structure, I don't think there is a way to do what you want using CSS only because till now there is no supported selectors for parents and grand parents in CSS.

Second thing I want to add is: there's no way to use the `display` property to change the image itself. Because `display` property specifies the display behavior of an element itself ... so, more again I suggest you to have a look on this topic [CSS display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Now, For your code, I've 2 suggestions:

(1): By make changes to HTML / CSS code

```css
        .responsive_right_side_block {
            width: 145px;
            height: 214px;
            background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        #frontal:hover ~ .responsive_right_side_block {
            background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300/000000/FFFFFF");
        }
```

```html
    <p class="p_not_1st">The three commonly referred to axis of rotation are:
        <ul class="ul_first">
            <li id="frontal">Frontal axis</li>
            <li>Sagittal axis</li>
            <li>Vertical axis</li>
            <div class="responsive_right_side_block"></div>
        </ul>
    </p>
```

And then, you can use css to style it as you want.

(2): Using JavaScript mouseover

```js
// select the image using it's class --> it's html collection so we need to specify the first index
        let img = document.getElementsByClassName('responsive_image')[0];

        // on mouse over of the li element --> the image src will change
        document.getElementById('frontal').onmouseover = function () {
            img.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/000000/FFFFFF');
        }

        // on mouse out of the li element --> the image src will return back to what is in html document
        document.getElementById('frontal').onmouseout = function () {
            img.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080');
        }
```

```html
    <div class="responsive_right_side_block"><img class="responsive_image" height="214"
            src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080" width="145"></div>

    <p class="p_not_1st">The three commonly referred to axis of rotation are:
        <ul class="ul_first">
            <li id="frontal">Frontal axis</li>
            <li>Sagittal axis</li>
            <li>Vertical axis</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
```